# Tomcat deploys older version of webapp

Tags: maven, tomcat, deployment, gitlab, gitlab-ci

This might be a duplicate, cause I can't image that we're the first to encounter this, but I can't seem to find it.

So, we are deploying WAR files to a tomcat 8.5 server with gitlab ci using maven. Issue is that tomcat messes up the versions when we moved from 0.2.9 to 0.2.10. Apparendly the server deploys the WARs in alphabetical order and 0.2.10 lies between 0.2.1 and 0.2.2 and the running version is still 0.2.9 even while 0.2.10 was correctly deployed to the server.

Full webapp name looks like: WebappName##0.2.10-SNAPSHOT_201901010000.war

We thought about renaming our versions to 0.2.009 and 0.2.010 but that seems like a rather dirty work-around. Of cause older versions will be deleted from time to time so it's not a permanent problem, but it's just somewhat annoying and any hints on how to solve this would be great.

From the pom.xml

```
<version>0.2.10-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.install.skip>true</maven.install.skip>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
[..]
<profile>
    <id>deploy-stage</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <war.name>WebappName##${project.version}_${timestamp}</war.name>
        <tomcat.url>http://[..]/manager/text</tomcat.url>
        <tomcat.server>[..]</tomcat.server>
        <tomcat.webpath>/${war.name}</tomcat.webpath>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-war</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest</goal>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                        <warName>${war.name}</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>true</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <forced>true</forced>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <packageName>true</packageName>
                            <useUniqueVersions>true</useUniqueVersions>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Build-Time>
                            <Archetype>${archetypeArtifactId}</Archetype>
                            <Archetype-Version>${archetypeVersion}</Archetype-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/web.xml</include>
                            </includes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warFile>${project.build.directory}/${war.name}.war</warFile>
                    <url>${tomcat.url}</url>
                    <server>${tomcat.server}</server>
                    <path>${tomcat.webpath}</path>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

From gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=WARN -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.showDateTime=true -Djava.awt.headless=true"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version -DinstallAtEnd=true -DdeployAtEnd=true"

# Cache downloaded dependencies and plugins between builds.
cache:
  paths:
    - /root/.m2/repository/

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

# Run deploy 
deploy:staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS -Dsonar.branch=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME deploy -am -P deploy-stage'
  only:
    - staging
  image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could edit your question by providing some more details about the parts of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` or the `pom.xml` where the steps related to the deployment are specified

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [Apache Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html) says:

> String comparisons are used to determine version order.

This is simply not the same as comparison of Maven artifact versions. A version of 2.0.2 is always larger by String comparison than 2.0.10 or even 2.0.15000 etc.

I guess you have something like this in your `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
  <buildTimestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</buildTimestamp>
  <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMddHHmm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
<build>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}##${project.version}_${maven.build.timestamp}</finalName>
</build>
```

You can change that to:

```
<finalName>${project.artifactId}##${maven.build.timestamp}_${project.version}</finalName>
```

which yields a file name like `WebappName##201901010000_0.2.10-SNAPSHOT.war`.

This way the most current build by timestamp will be deployed as currently active application version.

Alternatively you can keep your version schema of the .war file name and instead have your app deployed using a versioned file name for your context.xml:

`apache-tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/WebappName##201901010000.xml`
with the content:

```
<Context docBase="/path/to/WebappName##0.2.10-SNAPSHOT_201901010000.war" path="/WebappName"/>
```

In Apache Tomcat Manager this will show up as version 201901010000 in application version column. Again the most current build by timestamp will be deployed as currently active application version independent of the Maven artifact version as the deployment version String is taken from the .xml file name instead of the .war file name.

Comment: Putting the timestamp first is what we thought about as well, even tho it looks less intuitive. Will give an upvote, but wait with accepting. Thx.

Comment: that (answer+1), or you adjust your "versioning convention":..e.g. "nest at 10" (so: 2.9.9.1) ..or "zerofill" (2.09.10.11)